# scss how to reuse inner selector?

Tags: sass

I have code like this:

```
.outer1 {
  &.same-inner {
    background-color: white;
  }
}

.outer2 {
  &.same-inner {
    background-color: white;
  }
}

.outer3 {
  &.same-inner {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

How do I reuse .same-inner selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.outer1, .outer2, .outer3 {
  &.same-inner {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

Translates to CSS:

```
.outer1.same-inner, .outer2.same-inner, .outer3.same-inner {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Or if you wanted to give each of the outer's there own properties, but also inherit same-inner

```
.same-inner {
    background-color: white;
}

.outer1 {
    width:10px;
    @extend .same-inner  
}

.outer2 {
    width:20px;
    @extend .same-inner  
}

.outer3 {
    width:30px;
    @extend .same-inner  
}
```

Translates to CSS:

```
.same-inner, .outer1, .outer2, .outer3 {
  background-color: white;
}

.outer1 {
  width: 10px;
}

.outer2 {
  width: 20px;
}

.outer3 {
  width: 30px;
}
```

Or maybe what you want is:

```
.same-inner {
    background-color: white;
    
   &.outer1 {
        width:10px;
        @extend .same-inner
   }

   &.outer2 {
        width:20px;
        @extend .same-inner
   }
   
   &.outer3 {
        width:30px; 
        @extend .same-inner
   }
    
}
```

Which churns out CSS:

```
.same-inner, .same-inner.outer1, .same-inner.outer2, .same-inner.outer3 {
  background-color: white;
}

.outer1.same-inner {
  width: 10px;
}

.outer2.same-inner {
  width: 20px;
}

.outer3.same-inner {
  width: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse a selector by @extend.

follow this [sass documentation about @extend.](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend)